# How to work with large projects

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, best-practices, texworks

I am working on a project and i want to slim it down a litle so please help me with the
following. I have a document structure like this:

```
/DocumentRoot
 |-main.tex
 |-title.tex
 |
 |-/chapter-1
 |  |-/images
 |  |-chapter-1.tex
 |
 |-/chapter-2
    |-/images
    |-chapter-2.tex
```

My document is like this:

```
\begin{document}
\include{./title}
\include{./chapter-1/chapter-1}
\include{./chapter-2/chapter-2}
\include{./chapter-3/chapter-3}
\end{document}
```

in my chapters i use both some images and some heavy tikz plots so i use externalize and 
draft options for quicker compilation. But i want the images to be placed in the respective
chapter folders but for example in chapter 3 this works:

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./chapter-3/images/img.jpg}
```

and this doesn't

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./images/img.jpg}
```

for some reason xelatex has problems with the relative paths of included chapters. I also want to control the location output and the naming of the externalized tikz documents. Any help with that? I am working with miktex and texworks.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=docotherdir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is simple, just prepare directory paths (to import both chapter files and images files) whenever you include a new chapter.

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\Include#1{%
        \def\ChapterPath{#1/}%
        \def\GraphicsPath{\ChapterPath Images/}%
        \include{\ChapterPath#1}}

\newcommand\IncludeGraphics[2][width=\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{\GraphicsPath #2}}    

\begin{document}
    \Include{Chapter-1}
\end{document}
```

**Chapter-1.tex**

```
\chapter{Chapter One}


\IncludeGraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Tulips}
```

Remarks:

1. Folder `Chapter-1` is in `Docoment-Root` folder.
2. `Chapter-1.tex` is in folder `Chapter-1`.
3. `Tulips.jpg` is in  folder `Chapter-1/Images`.

### Tips

1. If your Ti*k*Z code is not "linked" to the text with nodes, for example, then put such Ti*k*Z code into a separate, compilable input file. Use `article` document class plus `preview` to get a tight PDF output. You can also use `standalone` document class instead.
2. If you table is not long enough to span across multiple pages, then put it into a separate, compilable input file to get a tight PDF output.
3. It is better not to specify the image extension explicitly when invoking `\includegraphics`.
4. Define macros for often-used materials and put them into a package such that you can change their definition later in one place and the changes effect the whole document.

Comment: See also my another answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143055/19356).

Comment: Will these macros work with import or subimport as well ?