# Is it possible to use includegraphics with relative path inside subfiles?

Tags: graphics, subfiles

### Question

I have many documents that I want to be merged inside one document. It could be for example a kind of year recap, with many different sources that use the same preambule like lectures, labs, assignments, tests, ...

I tried to use the `subfiles` package but I can't compile the main document because of relative path inside sub documents:

```
File `image.png' not found
```

Is it possible to include graphics inside a subfile using a relative path ?

### Minimal working example

I want a file `sub.tex` to be included inside a bigger document `main.tex`:

```
main.tex
sub/sub.tex
sub/image.png
```

The main document is not in the same directory as the sub document and is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
  Main file
  \subfile{sub/sub.tex}
\end{document}
```

My sub file `sub.tex` includes an image `image.png` with a relative path:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
  Sub file
  \includegraphics{image.png}
\end{document}
```

### What I tried

Following a comment below, I have defined two commands `Subfile` and `IncludeGraphics` in `main.tex` and I use them in both files:

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\SubfilePath{}
\def\Subfile#1{%
    \def\SubfilePath{\StrBefore{#1}{/}/}%
    \subfile{#1}}

\newcommand\IncludeGraphics[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{\SubfilePath #2}}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to compile `main.tex` whereas everything is fine with `sub.tex`:

```
Use of \Gin@ii doesn't match its definition
```

Comment: See my answer which is related to your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64205/19356

Comment: Interesting, but I still need to be able to compile my subfiles separately. Using you solution, I would therefore need to define a new `SubFile` command that calls `subfile` but stores the path somewhere for use inside a new `IncludeGraphics` command.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Package `graphics` provides `\graphicspath` that allows one to specify further directories for the search path of image files:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
  Main file

  \graphicspath{{sub/}}
  \subfile{sub/sub.tex}
\end{document}
```

Or `\graphicspath` can be called automatically for each `\subfile`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\makeatletter
\let\org@subfile\subfile
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
  \expandafter
  \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area}}%
  \org@subfile{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Main file
  \subfile{sub/sub.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention among the hundred documents I'm considering merging in a few ones, I use *images with the same name* and sometimes *different names for my image folders* (I will, one day, standardize everything). So it is a valid answer, but I think it will not work for my use case.

Comment: @remjg: (a) `\graphicspath` can be changed for every document setting a different path. (b) `\graphicspath` can be limited by a group: `\begingroup\graphicspath{{sub/}}\subfile{sub/sub.tex}\endgroup`.

Comment: Hoping this helps someone else here since it took a while to get it right. I had nested paths for my images, broken up by chapter. Nothing I was doing or finding online worked, until I did double `/`, e.g. `\graphicspath{{"Sections//Data Exchange//Images//"}}`