# Is it possible to use includegraphics with relative path with subfolder, inside subfiles?

Tags: graphics, xparse, subfiles

My question is a followup question of this:
[Is it possible to use includegraphics with relative path inside subfiles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172320/is-it-possible-to-use-includegraphics-with-relative-path-inside-subfiles)

I have my images in sub/image folder. I want automatically add 'sub/images' path for graphics, for each of the subfiles. Can any one help me edit the code so that it can do that?

This given code adds path to the subfiles, so that the image should be in the same path as the subfile. I want to keep the image in a subfolder.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\makeatletter
\let\org@subfile\subfile
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
  \expandafter
  \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area}}%
  \org@subfile{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Main file
  \subfile{sub/sub.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an [tag:xparse] solution?

Comment: I am looking for modification of the given code. I am not very efficient with expandafter commands:
\makeatletter
\let\org@subfile\subfile
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
  \expandafter
  \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area}}%
  \org@subfile{#1}%
}
\makeatother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** in light of [sajid's comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278568/is-it-possible-to-use-includegraphics-with-relative-path-with-subfolder-inside/278600?noredirect=1#comment671215_278600). But the additional `\expandafter` is not needed.

You can just append the sub-directory in the usual way.

```
  \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area img/}}%
```

This works even if the image needs conversion. (I copied the standard tiger image from the distribution, which needs to be converted for pdfTeX.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\makeatletter
\let\org@subfile\subfile
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
  \expandafter
  \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area img/}}%
  \org@subfile{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Main file
  \subfile{sub/sub.tex}
\end{document}
```

Hopefully this is the expected output:

[image: sub-tiger]

Comment: Excellent! It seemed rather too simple... ;).

Comment: Wait, I think I had a mistake. I copied my image file in the root. Actually, now that I removed my copy image file, the code didn't work any more.

Comment: Did you add your image in the img folder?

Comment: @sajid I thought so. I'll check. But not right now. Too lacking in consciousness. Maybe somebody else will find something meanwhile. ...

Comment: I solved the problem. \filename@area spits out a slash '/', and after img there must be a slash. Editing your code to \filename@area \expandafter images/ worked. Please edit your answer and I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @sajid Sorry. Yes. My original testing was flawed so I erroneously believed my code worked. I was going to delete this and suggest you accept your own solution. However, I'm leaving it for now just because the additional `\expandafter` in your code is not necessary. If you want to modify your solution and me to delete this, just let me know. (I'm assuming it is better not to use `\expandafter` here as it isn't needed.)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really need to do this in your TeX file, consider adding your subdirectory to the TEXINPUTS environmental variable before building (e.g., [Definition of the TEXINPUTS variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable)). It works OK, unless, of course, there are file name conflicts.

Comment: would TEXINPUT work if I don't have unique image files? And adding a directory of Image seems to be against abstraction. If I copy the Tex file to another computer, I would run into trouble

Comment: Technically, a TeX file by itself is never fully portable. The other computer may lack some style files, for instance. In my projects I use Makefiles to set the environment before build, which makes it more portable. If  you have conflicting file names, you will be always in trouble if you try to hide the prefixes.

Comment: This is not really answer. It should maybe be a comment, but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it, (with cfr's help). Basically add the name of the folder after the filename@area (which spits out the name of the directory of the subfile with a /)

```
\makeatletter
\let\org@subfile\subfile
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
  \expandafter
  \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area images/}}%
  \org@subfile{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```