# Is it possible to input tex files from subfolders inside subfiles?

Tags: input, include, subfiles

I want to automate the process of inputting tex files from subfolders. Previously I managed to automate the inclusion of images from "images" subfolder within the subfolder of each subfile. I would like to do the same for tex files. Please have a look at:
[Is it possible to use includegraphics with relative path with subfolder, inside subfiles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278568/is-it-possible-to-use-includegraphics-with-relative-path-with-subfolder-inside/278754#278754)

Now I want to add a modifier, so that

```
%subfolder1/subfile1.tex
\input{fig1.tex}
```

would add `subfolder1/fig1.tex` in the file, while

```
%subfolder2/subfile1.tex
\input{fig1.tex}
```

would add `subfolder2/fig1.tex` to my file.

Comment: Why not just define e.g. `\subinput{}` to use in an analogous way?

Comment: I am currently doing `\edef\CurrentFileDir{\currfiledir}` and  
`\renewcommand{\myimagedir}{\CurrentFileDir images/}`. `\input{\myimagedir fig_matlab_sinemodulation}` seems to work. Is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: What I had in mind was a new input command so you could say e.g. `\subinput{fig_matlab_sinemodulation}` - a wrapper around `\input{}`, in other words.

Comment: can you give any examples related to that? I am really a newbee in LaTeX. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I've posted an example. Are you sure **subfiles** doesn't provide something like this already? I've never used it, but this seems like the kind of thing people might often want to do and is a bit different from the graphics case (where mostly, setting the search path in the preamble or configuring different inputs for TeX will work). I understand use of `\graphicspath{}` is not considered good practice, by the way. That said, bad practice works well for me since I use it all the time.

Comment: Thank you for the example! it was great. I could not a path set option for subfile.

Comment: Glad it helped! (Took me an annoying amount of time to remember to double the `#` to `##` :(. I always forget this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might create a new command `\subinput{}` for handling this. Basically, this is a wrapper around `\input{}` which prefixes the relevant path.

File hierarchy for example is as follows:

```
<main filename>.tex
sub/
    sub.tex
    sub2.tex
    img/
        tigerx.eps
```

`sub/sub.tex`:

```
\documentclass[../<main filename>.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
  Sub file.

  Here's a tiger:

  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tigerx}

  \subinput{sub2}
\end{document}
```

`sub/sub2.tex`:

```
% sub/sub2.tex
That is some tiger!
\endinput
```

`<main filename>.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\makeatletter
\let\org@subfile\subfile
\newcommand*\subinput[1]{\input{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
  \expandafter
  \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area img/}}%
  \renewcommand*\subinput[1]{%
    \expandafter
    \input\expandafter{\expandafter\filename@area ##1}%
  }%
  \org@subfile{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Main file
  \subfile{sub/sub}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: sub-tigers with sub-sub annotations]